# Why sudden stresses cause stuttering and/or other impairs in children?

Tags: stress, children

The question is simple: Why sudden stresses cause stuttering and/or other temporary or permanent impairs in children (and even adults)?

Comment: The stuttering issue has an answer on http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8895/why-do-some-people-stutter-only-when-they-are-nervous/8911#8911.